# How do I sign my newly created Executable?

Tags: c#, certificate

I have developed an executable from a Visual C# project. Now whenever the app runs on other machines, the users are presented with a Smart Screen warning. I read more about it and it says that I need to sign my applications using Certificates.

Now the thing is that the Certificates from commercial companies cost a lot so is it possible to generate self signed certificates which can be used to sign the executable? If yes, then please explain how.

Also, is it possible that the Smart Screen warning disappear once many users start using it?

Is there any way also with which I can prevent tampering with the application?

Comment: Creating a self-signed certificate won't help because other pc's won't trust them.

Comment: IMO, it's not worth paying so much for a certificate unless you make a lot of money from it.

Comment: @ZippyV - The application is community based. Also will the warning disappear once many people start using it?